# Wait time for non-homogenous Poisson processes

Tags: poisson-process

Is the wait time between events for a non-homogenous Poisson process still exponentially distributed

Answer (score 2):

No.  Consider a process whose intensity is zero in the period $(0, 1)$, and then is one thereafter.  The waiting time is a translated exponential distribution.